# Totally unimodular matrix in norm minimization

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, unimodular-matrices

Let's say we have $l_1$ norm minimization $||Ax-b||_1$ with matrix $A$ with consecutive ones property. Now, we can construct a mathematical formulation to solve this problem:

\begin{align}
\text{min}  \, &\sum\limits_{i=1}^m s_i\\
&(1) \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j + s_i \geq b_i,\quad \forall i,\\
&(2) \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j - s_i \leq b_i,\quad \forall i\\
\end{align}

Now its clear that $[A,I]$ (matrix of constraint 1) and (matrix of constraint 2) $[A,-I]$ (proof can be done with using Laplacean expansion) are TU matrices, but its not clear that $\begin{bmatrix} A & I \\ A & -I \end{bmatrix}$ is which is the constraint matrix of this problem. I have seen empirically that I only get integer values for $x$ for all instances of $b$ I have tried, but it not clear to me that the constraint matrix is TU, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, unless $A$ has some other property. As a counter-example, you can take $A=(1)$ and $I$ of size $1$, you get determinant $-2$.

About your MIP...

If $Ax=b$ is feasible, then you get as obvious minimum $s=0$, and the constraint matrix becomes $(A^*,A^*)^*$ ($^*$ denoting transposition) which is TU (it verifies the consecutive ones property).

Do you still get only integer values when ensuring $Ax=b$ not feasible?

Comment: Good point Vincent. My instances for $A$ are like this http://pastebin.com/raw/Uv1nPp8k. So it has this consecutive ones property but its also very structured. If you have time and a LP solver, can you try my MIP with that constraint matrix I pasted and with any $b$. I get integer solutions with that and with similar matrices.

Comment: And yes, I get integer solutions even thought the I ensure such $b$ that $Ax \neq b$. I know that there are other classes of matrices than TU that describe integer polyhedrons, maybe the matrix I pasted is TU and with some additional trait that makes the constraint matrix have only integer vertices's.